# Improve multiclass text classification model with LSTM and Glove, Keras and Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, stanford-nlp, layer

I have spent some time trying to improve my F1-Score for my multiclass text classification task. I am extraction aspects and sentiments from laptop reviews. Therefore there are 3 labels, B_A / I_A / O etc. I would really appreciate any suggestions to improve my network, for example additional layers or another embedding. (Maybe I should also try something else than multiclass classification for my task)
Now I have got a F1-Score of about 60% for the following code:

```
#vocab_size=4840, embedding is glove6B, max_seq_length=100

model =  Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, 300, weights=[embedding_vectors], input_length=max_seq_length, 
trainable= False))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Conv1D(3000, 1, activation='relu'))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units=150, recurrent_dropout=0, return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(n_tags, activation='softmax'))


model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="rmsprop", metrics=["categorical_accuracy"])
model.summary()

# fit model on train data
model.fit(x_train, y_train,
      batch_size=64,
      epochs=10)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the data, but I do have a lot of suggestions in general for mult-text classification with keras:

1. Instead of adding 1 3000 Conv1D layer, try adding multiple Conv1D layers of a smaller filtering amount
2. For the 32 neuron Dense layer, try increasing the amount of neurons. Often, when you don't have enough neurons in the layer before the output layer, the model loses accuracy
3. Instead of adding activation='relu' into the layers, instead try adding a LeakyReLU, so it would fix the dying ReLU problem if it is there
4. Instead of adding the Dropout after the Embedding layer, add the Dropout after the Conv1D layer. I wouldn't see the need for a Dropout after an untrainable layer made just for vectorizing inputs

If you haven't tried any of my suggestions already, I would recommend trying it. I especially would try the 4th one, as a Dropout after an Embedding layer doesn't seem neccessary.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! Unfortunately it did not improve my f1-score. Any further ideas? I read about a character embedding, maybe try that?